# How should be interpreted this note about the floating point?

Tags: digital-logic, floating-point

In an old class notes I have found something that puzzles me since I don't grasp how it works.
The notes says

> **Floating point numbers representation **
>   In general if \$N=\pm(a_{n-1}...a_{0}...a_{m})_{r}\$, then \$N\$ could be written as
>   $$N=F\times r^E$$
>   where
>   $$F=\pm(a_{n-1}...a_{m})_{r}$$
>   $$E=\pm(b_{k-1}...b_{o})_{r}$$
>   so the fractional part \$F\$ is multiplied by the \$r\$ base raised to the power \$E\$.
>   Let \$S_{F}\$ be the sign for \$F\$ y \$S_{E}\$ the sign for \$E\$, then the floating point representation reduced is:
>   $$N=(S_{E}S_{F},b_{k-1}...b_{o},a_{n-1}...a_{m})_{r}$$
>   with \$S_{F}\$ and \$S_{E}\$ equals to  \$0\$ or \$1\$ for \$F\$ and \$E\$.
>
> Example
>   $$N=(1.650000)_{10}$$ 
>    for \$n+m=5\$ and \$k=3\$, 
>   \$F\$ and \$E\$  would be
>   $$F=+(0.16500)_{10}$$ 
>   $$E=+(0.007)_{10}$$
>   Then
>
> $$N=(00,007,16500)_{10}$$

I'm guessing that its like when you convert a fractional decimal to binary starting to multiply the number by the base 2 but I don't know why the  E and F coefficients, nor what the n,m and k are and how are assigned.

Could please explain how the theory part is applied to the example?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

Comment: I can't fathom is where they get the value 007 for E. Not yet, anyway. ... Never mind. I think I see where that comes from, now. This isn't really floating point in the usual sense. It appears to also include implicit precision of the original value. By this, I mean that 1.65 is NOT the same as 1.650, if I'm gathering up things correctly. Tricky. E is 7 because the original number specifies 7 places of precision.

Comment: I think the k values is arbitrary , but yes I wonder why the 7

Comment: Yes, k appears to be an input (arbitrary) to the format. As is n and m.